Movie about a Boy who doesn't talk and his parents murdered by his sister
So I saw this movie years ago, and I can't find it anywhere. I watched in 2008, the guide's channel said that was The Silence of the Lambs, but I know it isn't, and it was really late so I think that they misplaced the name. I'm pretty sure the movie was in English.
I don't know the name, but it is about two siblings, a boy and a girl. Their parents were murdered. The boy has some kind of mental illness and he doesn't talk. He just copies sounds that he hears, and he's pretty good. The cops find some pornographic pictures of him and find out that their parents were the one who took it. He is the primer suspected. But in the end it was his sister who killed their parents to save him. And the detective adopt him. Any idea? 

do you remember the release year, language or country? Anything that can help identify this movie.

I watched in 2008, the guide's channel said that was the silence of the lambs, but i know it isn't, and it was really late so I think that they misplaced the name. I'm pretty sure the movie was in english.

Feel free to [edit] any additional information into the question.

I believe it is Silent Fall (1994)
From Wikipedia:

Tim Warden, a boy with autism, has supposedly witnessed his parents' double murder. Jake Rainer, a former child psychiatrist turned therapist, is called on to probe the child's mind in order to solve the case.

and

It was actually Sylvie who killed her parents because her father had raped her repeatedly and was trying to do the same to Tim, and her mother was aware of the abuse and stayed silent the entire time.

Jake also adopts the boy in the end.
